# JavaScript/jQuery key not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a dictionary in Javascript which I am passing to a function in Django. But when I try to access the data in POST it says that the key message is not found when the key clearly exists. Ive been scratching my head over this one. Im new to Javascript and Jquery so im sure I made a simple mistake.

Heres the code:

```
function share(id) {
  var message = $('textarea#message').val();
  var postData = { message: message, id: id };
  $.post( "/{{ username }}/post/", postData, function ( json ) {
    $('#posts').load(' #posts', function(){$(this).children().unwrap()})
  } );
}
```

The exact error:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /Mohammed/post/ "Key 'message' not found in " Request Method: POST

**UPDATE**
So I have narrowed down the issue and its that var message is not getting a value. The html which I am trying to grab the value from is as follows:

```
 <textarea class="input-xlarge inputConvo"  value = "" name="message" id="textarea" rows="2" style="width:98%; min-width:98%; max-width:98%;" placeholder="Share something with <user>."></textarea>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox and examine the exact contents of the POST that is being sent. It may be quite instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! You are not getting at the element correctly. Try this:

```
var message = $('#textarea').val();
```

The `#` syntax means get the element with the `id` of *textarea*. Not the name. You can change the `id` to *message* and use `$('#message').val();`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery portion looks good to me. Make sure you are doing the following on the server side:

```
message = request.POST['message']
```

if that doesn't work, you can try the following, which will look at GET and POST simultaneously.

```
message = request.REQUEST['message']
```

If you still haven't got any luck, try printing `request.POST` and `request.REQUEST` to the console, e.g.

```
print request.REQUEST
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. The key doesn't exist in the dictionary in request.Im updating the question cause I believe Ive narrowed down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract data from you `dict` objects in a safer way, like this:

```
request.REQUEST.get('message', '')
```

This will avoid any `Key not found` errors. Just make the default values whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I use a POST.has_key() to make sure it exists but this is another nice alternative.